# Single query to collect data from multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

I have a problem collecting data from an SQL database that I designed.

This is a table of questions of different types, each type has it's own table with different columns and has the questionid as a foreign key that referenced this table as seen below.

```
 Column   |          Type          | Modifiers
------------+------------------------+-----------
 questionid | integer                | not null
 header     | character varying(500) |
Indexes:
    "quizquestion_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (questionid)
Referenced by:
    TABLE "matchingpairs" CONSTRAINT "matchingpairs_questionid_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (questionid) REFERENCES quizquestion(questionid)
    TABLE "mcqchoices" CONSTRAINT "mcqchoices_questionid_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (questionid) REFERENCES quizquestion(questionid)
    TABLE "questionsinquiz" CONSTRAINT "questionsinquiz_questionid_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (questionid) REFERENCES quizquestion(questionid)
    TABLE "truefalsequestion" CONSTRAINT "truefalsequestion_questionid_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (questionid) REFERENCES quizquestion(questionid
)
```

I have another table that keeps up which question belongs to which quiz using also the questionid

```
   Column   |  Type   | Modifiers
------------+---------+-----------
 quizid     | integer | not null
 questionid | integer | not null
 index      | integer |
Indexes:
    "questionsinquiz_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (quizid, questionid)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "questionsinquiz_questionid_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (questionid) REFERENCES quizquestion(questionid)
    "questionsinquiz_quizid_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (quizid) REFERENCES quiz(quizid)
```

Is there a way to collect all the different questions in one query or do I have to query on every question type, or is there something different that I can change in the database table design.

Comment: You have the tables separated out by type, so you can use a union (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/queries-union.html) to combine the results of the queries. A better design would have been to use a question type table and have question type column in the questions table referencing that table.

Comment: What sort of output are you looking for?  Select questionid from table1?

Comment: I'm asking is there a way I can use a single query to collect all the questions information belonging to a single quiz, given every question has different columns? Or do I have to just query for every question type alone by itself and then collect all the different questions after multiple queries?

Comment: What do you mean every question type has different columns? Show us the tables for two different types and what you want the output to look like.... Be nice to have a simplified example with sample data.

Comment: `matchingPairs (Statement1, Statement2, PairNumber, QuestionID)  
,  
mcqchoices (Choice, isCorrect, ChoiceNumber, QuestionID)`

these are two of the tables that I use
due to the dynamic number of mcq choices in the mcq question, I store every choice as an entry in the `mcqchoices` table, same goes for the `matchingpairs`

Comment: And how do you make sure that two tables don't have the same question ID? What you are doing is still possible with a single question table like I mentioned before and then reference the ID in the two tables you have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your description, you can use Postgres inheritance.  This is a facility where tables can be related to each other.  The place to start learning about it is in the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-inherit.html).

Using inheritance, you would have a parent table called `questions` which defines `questionId` and other related columns.  Then you can define multiple other tables such as `matchingPairsQuestions` which inherit from `questions`.  Queries and foreign keys can then refer either to the individual "children" tables or to all of them as a single set.

Comment: I think inheritance would not work in my case because for example `matchingpairs` table has columns `matchingPairs (Statement1, Statement2, PairNumber, QuestionID) `, so a single matching question can have many rows in the `matchingPairs` table do due a dynamic design of the number of pairs in the matching, is there a better way I can design the DB tables so I can reach a simple query to just collect all the quiz questions of all their types? or do I have to just collect the question data of every type in a separate query?
Thanks